# Prestashop 1.6 vouchers not applied to other addresses

Tags: php, ajax, e-commerce, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

so I set up free shipping vouchers above a certain price in Prestashop 1.6 (free shipping with carrier X above $XXX for certain countries, free shipping with carrier Y above $YYY for certain other countries).

But when on the cart page (one page checkout) I change the shipping address to a second address it does not apply these free shipping vouchers. They are only applied on the first address.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Thanks!